# Do Picard & co. have magic rope?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, logistics

In "Chain of Command", Picard, Worf and Crusher need to rappel down a 500m-long chasm.

Now, surely, they can't have 500m of rope in each of their backpacks, right? They must have some kind of arrangement where they rappel a very short distance, then release the petons, reaffix them further below, and rappel some more. Or - maybe some other way to rappel down?

I don't have significant climbing experience so I don't know how this thing would work.

Comment: There. Are. 4. Ropes!

Comment: _"They must have some kind of arrangement where they rappel a very short distance, then release the petons, reaffix them further below, and rappel some more."_ But then how would they get back up?

Comment: @LogicDictates: Getting up is actually easier: You only use the rope to secure yourself to the peton, and advance by moving the set of petons below you to a new position above. 6 petons per person should be enough for that. Of course it's not much fun to do it for 500 meters straight...

Comment: @einpoklum - Doesn't sound easier to me.

Comment: surely they have positronic space rope which is always just as long as required.

Comment: *Journey to the Center of the Earth* explains how to rappel down a slope a section at a time, using a rope much to short to descend the entire distance in one go.

Comment: @Buzz: Yes, that's what I assume is happening, but - the episode is filmed as though, whoosh, the rope extends 500m down.

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." - Some SciFi Guy.

Comment: "There are four ropes!" That's funny Valorum.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing in the [original script](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/236.txt) or [episode transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/236.htm) to indicate that the chasm wasn't 500 meters deep, nor that the ropes didn't reach to the bottom of the abyss.

In this instance, you just have to suspend your disbelief that that's [500m of rope](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/714Ky1nOgpL._AC_SL1500_.jpg), not 100(ish). Maybe it's special futuristic rope that stretches.

> 37   POV PICARD - THE ABYSS (MATTE SHOT)
>
> A yawning chasm opens up below the precipice. There are distant walls and shapes dimly seen down the abyss, but the bottom is far out of sight.
>
> ...
>
> **BEVERLY:** *The bottom's a little over five hundred meters.*
>
> Picard now attaches a line to the piton, clips the line into his harness and then tosses the coil of rope over the edge. Worf and Beverly secure their own pitons and attach their own ropes.
>
> {Later}
>
> INT. CAVERNS - CAVE BOTTOM
>
> Picard and Worf are standing at the bottom of the abyss. It's a flat area, branching out into more tunnels. Beverly is still on the rope, taking the last few steps down the rock face. She jumps to the bottom and Worf helps her unhook the line from her harness. Picard scans the area with a tricorder.

Comment: Rope that stretches... but there was no stretch when they released the rope. Also, it would de-stretch if they ever let go of it for a second while repelling down. Also, 100m of rope is also rather unlikely - even it terms of volume rather than weight.

Comment: @einpoklum - [Bellisario's Maxim](https://tropedia.fandom.com/wiki/Bellisario%27s_Maxim) applies here. It's actually three actors standing on a set made of styrofoam with a crew that is too busy worrying about whether the lights are making Patrick Stewart's shiny head bounce to spot that the rope isn't long enough to match up with the script.

Comment: But this problem would have been resolved, or introduced, while writing the script; it is not a matter the on-set people suddenly notice.

Comment: One could imagine a rope which stretches (and thins) in response to applied current (for instance).  Remove the current (or other conditioner)  and the rope returns to its thickened, shortened form.  Not at all suggested in the episode, of course.

Comment: @JohnHunt: I guess it must rope that's treated with [phlebotinum](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum) then.